# Lerna command in AWS Codebuild

Tags: continuous-integration, continuous-deployment, aws-codepipeline, aws-codebuild, lerna

```
Error: Cannot find module '.'
Require stack:
- /codebuild/output/src309915592/src/node_modules/.bin/lerna
    at Function.Module._resolveFilename (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:831:15)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:687:27)
    at Module.require (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:903:19)
    at require (internal/modules/cjs/helpers.js:74:18)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/codebuild/output/src309915592/src/node_modules/.bin/lerna:11:3)
    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1015:30)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1035:10)
    at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:879:32)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:724:14)
    at Function.executeUserEntryPoint [as runMain] (internal/modules/run_main.js:60:12) {
  code: 'MODULE_NOT_FOUND',
  requireStack: [ '/codebuild/output/src309915592/src/node_modules/.bin/lerna' ]
}
```

I get this error on running the test command:

```
lerna run --stream test --parallel
```

Also, tried with

```
lerna run --stream test --parallel --scope tenant-registration-service
```

In the services, test script looks like,

```
"test": "serverless-bundle test --verbose --coverage",
```

I installed Lerna globally in the pipeline.  How do I debug this? What module is it not able to find? It looks like it already has lerna installed which it should.

npm run test command runs just fine on the local system.